# Creating a Single Container Virtual Data Folder

Tags: windows, virtualization

I have been searching everywhere for all the combinations of things that I want to accomplish hoping something would pop but I can't find anything. Additionally, I am not sure if I am "crafting" my query properly enough so I am hoping I can get some assistance on that here.

What I would like to accomplish is this (pseudo logic)

- Create a single container file, for example: vdata.x which will contain everything in it as a single data file
- Mount this file as an actual drive/folder in Windows so that you can write to, read from, delete/modify the content as if you were using Windows Explorer. Visible to FS, applications, system/commandline like any other "real" folder on the machine.
- Prefer the ability to have this file reside on a thumbdrive and have it mounted either automatically or manually after plugged in and have it show up not as the thumbdrive but as the file inside it, or mount both doesn't matter.
- Additionally the ability for that file to be locked, encrypted and accessible (despite auto mounting, if that's the case) after it have been authenticated with a password, random token or whatnot.
- Finally a housekeeping element, such as being aware of its available "host" space (aka the thumbdrive) so that as it reaches a certain threshold of expansion, it says, hey move me to a larger device, make room or stop adding more, something akin to, running out of space warning.

I thought about putting this in software recommendation SE but that is not fully up and running yet (at last check) and plus the range of who access that sub-se might very limited, so I am asking here to get feedback and discussion to see if we can answer it better here or it needs to move to there.

Thank you in advance and hope to get some brilliant minds out there to help me accomplish this.

PS. I am not averse to building something like this myself but I am limited in time and health and plus if its already done, why reinvent the wheel right? But if anything could help launch the development of such a tool, I would take that input as well, thank you.

Comment: I was hoping for something on this by now, no takers?

Comment: added that I want to do this on windows in the hopes that it gets more consideration, it was assumed so that's why I didn't add it originally, let's see

Comment: I believe the edit to remove the `data-vault` tag was a mistake given that is pertains wholly to the subject, it does a disservice to make it more obscure and irrelevant rather than help answer it.